# SQLAlchemy: Use Enum within a Mixin [PostgreSQL]

Tags: python, postgresql, enums, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use an `Enum` within my Mixin model

The mixin model looks this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Enum
from enum import Enum as EnumClass

class MyEnum(EnumClass):
    active = 1
    deactive = 2
    deleted = 3

class MyMixin:
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    status = Column(Enum(MyEnum), nullable=False, unique=False, default=MyEnum.active)
```

And I have other models inheriting my mixin like this:

```py
class Inherited1(MyMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_table_1'


class Inherited2(MyMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_table_2'
```

I'm using PostgreSQL as my Database, when I try to use `Base.metadata.create_all()`, It return's the following error:

```py
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) type "myenum" already exists
```

The reason is It's trying to recreate the enum type in the PostgreSQL, a workaround would be defining the enum on the inherited classes and passing `name` parameter to the `Enum` type used for the column

But I wanted to know is there any better way to use `MyMixin` with the `Enum` type and inherit it for multiple models?

I should add that I am using Alembic for migrating, I even tried to add `create_type=False` as a parameter to `sa.Enum()` within the `sa.Column()` defination for my Enum type, and it didn't work, like this:

```py
sa.Column('status', sa.Enum('active', 'deactive', 'deleted', name='myenum', create_type=False), nullable=False)
```

**Workaround**:
I added this part to the question, cause still I don't think it's the best practice to do it

I edited the migration script by changing `sa.Enum()` to `sa.dialects.postgresql.ENUM()`

```
sa.Column('status', sa.dialects.postgresql.ENUM('active', 'deactive', 'deleted', name='myenum', create_type=False), nullable=False)
```

Seems like the `sa.Enum` type doesn't take `create_type` parameter since it is exclusively for PostgreSQL

But I'm still looking for a better way that doesn't require making changes to the migration script